# Find location of an image in a Word 2003 document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003

As per the title how can I find the `image location` of an image inserted in to a Word 2003 document?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Perhaps include an example?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not for Word 2003 but if it is a matter of finding the source to which an image is linked then the following might work:

Right click on the image (may require two clicks). A menu should pop up including something like **Linked Photo Editor Photo Object**  click on that, click on **Links** and where **Source file:** should show the file name and full path.